# MySQL Replication and Master server crash recovery

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, master-slave

Scenario:

We have a mySQL master DB [30 GB] with 5 slaves[partial] that are being used for different purposes.
Last day innodb crashed. Auto crash recovery did not work as on every write operation the server was getting crashed again. So I started the server with innodb_force_recovery 4 and took a dump of the whole DB and then restored into a new database server. This whole process took me over 5 hours as the data restoration was very slow.

QUestion:

Now I am looking for some solution in which the recovery time is quickest. I can have another server in replication with master but not sure how I will replace that in place of the master in case of master crashes.

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Good read from Percona: [Improving InnoDB recovery time](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/07/improving-innodb-recovery-time/)